# What does it mean by a force acting horizontally?

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, vectors, classical-mechanics, angle

**Question:**

A body of $10kg-wt$ is kept in an equilibrium condition by a force of $5kg-wt$ acting horizontally, a force of $F\ kg-wt$ acting at an angle $60^{\circ}$ with the horizon and a force of $R\ kg-wt$ acting perpendicular to $F$. Show that $F-\sqrt{3}R+10=0$.

**My book's attempt:**

[image]

$$5\cos(0^{\circ})+10\cos(-90^{\circ})+F\cos(60^{\circ})+R\cos(150^{\circ})=0$$

$$5+0+\frac{F}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}R}{2}=0$$

$$10+F-\sqrt{3}R=0$$

$$F-\sqrt{3}R+10=0\ \text{(showed)}$$

**My attempt:**

[image]

$$5\cos(0^{\circ})+10\cos(-90^{\circ})+R\cos(30^{\circ})+F\cos(120^{\circ})=0$$

$$5+0+\frac{\sqrt{3}R}{2}-\frac{F}{2}=0$$

$$10+\sqrt{3}R-F=0$$

**My comments:**

I was not able to prove the statement given in the question while my book was able to. This is because my figure is different than that of my book, but I believe that I didn't do anything outside the capacity of the question. I think I drew the figure according to the question. The difference between my attempt and my book's attempt is that I drew the horizontal force acting towards the left while my book drew it acting towards the right. Both should be correct, according to the question, since the book didn't specify towards which side, left or right, the horizontal force was acting on. Then why was I unable to prove the statement in the question?

**My question:**

1. Why couldn't I prove the question statement correctly when I drew the figure according to the question?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio "But it is also worth noting that R being perpendicular to F would allow for two orientations for R in your setup, whereas the book's setup allows for only one orientation for equilibrium to hold." Well, in my setup, I've already drawn one of the two possible orientations, according to you. I'm having difficulty finding the other orientation. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Well R could be 90 degrees clockwise or counterclockwise from F. But I removed my comment because clearly there are implicit conventions used in your book. Otherwise, by this reasoning, "acting at an angle 60 degrees" is also ambiguous (but conventionally, angles are measured counterclockwise)

Comment: 1. I don't understand why all the quantities have "kg-wt" attached to their specification. 2. When an author writes "a force of 17N acting at 60 degrees clockwise with the horizon", it is clear to me that 17N is a scalar not a vector or signed value and that "60 degrees clockwise with the horizon" fully specifies its direction (in other words, the signed value in "a force of -17N acting at 120 degrees anticlockwise with the horizon" is extremely unconventional). Therefore, "a force of 5N acting horizontally" is ambiguous to me.

Comment: 3. "Acting perpendicular to F" is also ambiguous: In the first diagram, once the other vectors have been drawn, R only has only possibility; whereas in the second diagram, I would ask "clockwise perpendicular or counterclockwise perpendicular?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The difference between my attempt and my book's attempt is that I drew the horizontal force acting towards the left while my book drew it acting towards the right. Both should be correct, according to the question, since the book didn't specify towards which side, left or right, the horizontal force was acting on. Then why was I unable to prove the statement in the question?

Force is a vector, and implicitly has direction as well as magnitude.

A force of $5 \text{ kg m/s}^2$ horizontally implicitly has positive direction, because $5>0$. If we center our coordinate system at whatever is being pushed, then positive direction is (by convention) to the right).

Similarly, a force of $-5 \text{ kg m/s}^2$, having negative direction, would be going left in this scenario.

In fact, the same could be said for angles; in this scenario, we measure the angle starting from the positive side of the $x$-axis. (Otherwise, an angle of $-60^\circ$ would still trace out the same angle, in terms of size, but be in the wrong quadrant.)

Comment: "In fact, the same could be said for angles; in this scenario, we measure the angle starting from the positive side of the x-axis." I'm having some trouble understanding what you are meaning here: are you trying to say that the convention for measuring angles is from the positive side i.e. from the right side or the positive side of the horizon just as the convention is for positive forces to act towards the right of the horizon?

Comment: What I'm saying is that angles and forces are similar, in that they have a "directional" component. Angles, by convention, have their "positive direction" being clockwise rotation, and negative counterclockwise; forces acting horizontally in a system like this by convention have their positive direction to the right.